# Difference in meaning in "insulation" vs. "isolation"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the two? I often saw them used interchangeably until a while ago

*If you must use two metals farther apart than 200mV, you need to take steps to protect them, either by **insulation** or **isolation** (so they're not in contact) or by using anodes.*

If someone knows to explain on a practical example?

Comment: Have you considered looking up the definitions on-line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example sentence uses sense 3 of [insulation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insulation#Noun), "...separating a body from others by nonconductors, so as to prevent the transfer of electricity..." and sense 1 of [isolation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isolation#Noun), "state of being isolated, detached, or separated".

Electrical isolation amounts to using an air gap (or vacuum) as an insulating (nonconducting) medium; like most electrical insulators, air has a [breakdown voltage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakdown_voltage#Insulators), typically about 1000V/mm, while the breakdown voltage in partial vacuum may be substantially less.

Comment: So, if I may, "insulation" would be wrapping the wire in thick plastic, while "isolation" would be separating the wire from anything outside wishing it "harm"? To put it bluntly.

Comment: Yes, if the plastic is nonconductive, which usually is the case.  "Insulating" typically means using a tangible barrier to reduce conduction, while "isolating" means separating by a distance suitable for the voltages involved.

Comment: @Idigas: I think it would be more appropriate to say that "isolation" is separating it from other electrical components, regardless of whether there's any harm involved.